# Как сделать так, чтобы рандомное число в боте дискорд не повторялось?

Tags: бот, discord.py

Проблема в том, что когда я пишу команду /card, у меня генерируется случайное число. Но когда я пишу команду ещё раз, бот пишет то же число, которое и было в прошлый раз. Как сделать так, чтобы рандомное число менялось без перезагрузки бота? Вот мой код:

```
import random
import discord
from discord import Intents

randomcrd = random.randint(1,100)


intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="Личное"))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('{0.author} написал сообщение: {0.content}'.format(message))

        if message.content == "/weeknews":
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Личное", description="Личное", color=0x00ff00)
            embedVar.add_field(name="Личное", value="Личное", inline=False)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

        if message.content == "/card":
            if randomcrd >= 50:
                await message.channel.send(f"Молодец! Результат: {randomcrd}!")
            elif randomcrd <= 50:
                await message.channel.send(f"Не молодец. Результат {randomcrd}.")


        

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('здесь токен')
```

Comment: Посмотри, где и когда у тебя генерируется случайное число. В каком месте кода оно должно измениться, когда ты пишешь команду?

Comment: В переменной randomcrd, наверное..

Comment: А где на самом деле? Как мне исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Да, в переменной randomcrd. Один раз присвоил случайное число. Потом прислал команду, что после этого происходит с переменной randomcrd?

Comment: Она остаётся с таким же значением?

Comment: Это понятно. А в коде что с ней происходит? Код получил команду, что он делает с переменной? Я вопросы задаю не чтобы ты мне объяснил, а чтобы ты сам понял, в чем проблема.

Comment: Что в коде происходит с ней не знаю :(

Comment: А. Скорее всего поскольку переменная randomcrd находится за пределами команды, код получает эту переменную, генерирует рандомное число, и я в команде просто вставляю это сгенерированное число. Наверное, чтобы оно регенерировалось, я должен вставить эту переменную в команду?

Comment: Да, нужно вставить генерацию случайного числа в обработчик команды.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Без вас бы не понял, да ещё вы дали мне самому понять! Ещё раз огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @Froxerys почитайте про реализацию команд: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/problems/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20on_message.md